# Is there any way to get jQuery ajax upload progress?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```js
$.ajax({
  xhr: function()
  {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with upload progress
        console.log(percentComplete);
      }
    }, false);
    //Download progress
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with download progress
        console.log(percentComplete);
        }
      }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/",
  data: {},
  success: function(data){
    //Do something success-ish
  }
});
```

This does not work on jQuery 1.5+ because the xhr is replaced by the jqXHR (i.e. a high level version of the raw XHR.) Now the question is how to get it to work with jqXHR…
Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of the given post, the given post doesn't even use jQuery, and jQuery is the cause of this problem.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.5, `$.ajax()` returns a jqXHR object, which implements the Promise interface. I guess that you can monitor progress with '$.ajax(...).progress(callback)`. Unfortunately, I can't find a full refernce so can't advise of what parameters the callback accepts, though it's probably the same as a `done` (success) callback, ie. `function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){...}`. **[The jqXHR Object](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)** exposes a bunch of properties and methods which can be exploited in the callback.

Answer (score 12):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: path,
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function (e) {
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                console.log(e.loaded / e.total);
            }
        };
        return xhr;
    }
}).done(function (e) {

})
```

Answer (score 4):

I made a jquery plugin to handle upload or download progress events in a easy way. Works any jquery ajax method such as $.ajax, $.get, $getJSON, $.post, etc. You can download it from here: https://github.com/cvelazquez/jquery.ajax.progress

```
var jqXHR = $.post('www.somedomain.com', {data:"real long data, o maybe a file upload"}, function(response){
    /* do anything on finish */
});

$(jqXHR).on('uploading', function(proxyEvent, event){
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        // You can do anything here
        console.log("Uploaded " + parseInt( (event.loaded / event.total * 100), 10) + "%");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching around the documentation and other questions, there appears to be a plugin to monitor the jquery ajax progress: https://github.com/hiddentao/jquery.ajaxprogress

Comment: The plugin you linked does not provide percentages, only an indicator if the upload is in progress or not. Not helpful.