# Ajax progress not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a small problem here. I'm uploading some image data via AJAX to my PHP script. The entire script works well except the progress part.

The only thing in console I get is

`Upload1`

then

`Ajax done`

Javasript:

```
$.ajax({
                xhr: function(){
                    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                        //Upload progress
                        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                //Do something with upload progress
                                    console.log("upload"+percentComplete);
                        }
                        }, false);
                            //Download progress
                            xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                            if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                                var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                                //Do something with download progress
                                console.log("download:"+percentComplete);
                        }
                    }, false);
                    return xhr;
                },
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: {
                    image: img,
                    designID: dID,
                }
            }).done(function( newID ) {
                console.log("ajax done");
            });
```

I assumed the upload would count up from 1 to 100%. I tried to do some loops but it didn't work.. Any idea what's happening

Cheers

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to get jQuery ajax upload progress?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13203231/is-there-any-way-to-get-jquery-ajax-upload-progress)

Comment: Have you tried a really big image? It would never count up really nicely though, it would only be when multipart request/responses came back and the XmlHttpRequest object fired a state changed event, which might be quite intermittently.

Comment: In which browser did you check this? And did you check it in another browser?

Comment: @Damon current picture is approx 100KB

Comment: @Prutswonder I checked this in Google Chrome v34

Comment: if you're running locally it might be too fast to see any updates, the only events you'll receive are the initial and the finished. You might have more luck with a really big file, and/or using a proxy debugger like Charles or Fiddler to artifically slow down your throughput.

Answer (score 0):

Add `async:true` in your ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
                xhr: function(){...},
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                async: true,
                data: {
                    image: img,
                    designID: dID,
                }
            }).done(function( newID ) {
                console.log("ajax done");
            });
```